# Construction of $R$-graph from a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, research, directed-graphs

Let $G$ be a finite directed graph with vertex set $V$ and an edge set $E$. In this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.2578.pdf, another graph is constructed from $G$ called $R$-graph by the following way:

- On page 2, line-5 of the paper whose link is given above, Authors choose a partition $\{E^{-}, E^+\}$ of $E$.
- In page 2, line-13, for any $q, r \in V$, Authors choose a relation $\mathcal R(q, r) \subset E^{-}(q, r) \times E^+(q, r)$

> > I have doubts about this partition and relation.  Whether this partition $\{E^{-}, E^+\}$, and relation $\mathcal R(q, r)$ are fixed or for any partition $\{E^{-}, E^+\}$ and relation $\mathcal R(q, r)$, we can construct $R$-graph?

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Krieger is simply defining his notion of $\mathcal{R}$-graph. It is an object $\mathcal{G}_{\mathcal{R}}(\mathfrak{P},\mathcal{E}^-,\mathcal{E}^+)$, where $\mathfrak{P}$ is the vertex set of a finite directed graph with edge set $\mathcal{E}$, $\{\mathcal{E}^-,\mathcal{E}^+\}$ is a partition of $\mathcal{E}$, the graph satisfies certain conditions, and $\mathcal{R}$ is a relation on the edges that also satisfies certain conditions.

Specifically, for $\mathfrak{q},\mathfrak{r}\in\mathfrak{P}$ we define $\mathcal{E}^-(\mathfrak{q},\mathfrak{r})$ to be the set of edges in $\mathcal{E}^-$ from $\mathfrak{q}$ to $\mathfrak{r}$ and $\mathcal{E}^+(\mathfrak{q},\mathfrak{r})$ to be the set of edges in $\mathcal{E}^+$ from $\mathfrak{r}$ to $\mathfrak{q}$. For each $\mathfrak{q},\mathfrak{r}\in\mathfrak{P}$ we require that either both of these sets be empty or both be non-empty, and we further require that the directed graph $\langle\mathfrak{P},\mathcal{E}^-\rangle$ (and hence also ($\langle\mathfrak{P},\mathcal{E}^+\rangle$) be strongly connected.

The relation $\mathcal{R}$ is the union of relations $\mathcal{R}(\mathfrak{q},\mathfrak{r})\subseteq\mathcal{E}^-(\mathfrak{q},\mathfrak{r})\times\mathcal{E}^+(\mathfrak{q},\mathfrak{r})$ for $\mathfrak{q},\mathfrak{r}\in\mathfrak{P}$.

And that’s it: any object satisfying those conditions is an $\mathcal{R}$-graph in the sense of this definition. If you change any of the parameters — the vertex set $\mathfrak{P}$, the edge set $\mathcal{E}$, the partition of the edge set, or the relation $\mathcal{R}$ — you have either a different $\mathcal{R}$-graph, if the various structural conditions are still met, or something that is not an $\mathcal{R}$-graph.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for the helpful answer.  In this paper, I have not seen anywhere the various structural condition for $R$-graph.  Can you mention these conditions here?

Comment: @Struggler: This material is completely new to me, I’m afraid: it’s not my field at all. I know just enough about these ideas to make sense of the definitions.

Comment: Its ok sir,  I will try to get more information.